# Pulsar: If a message gets nack'd (negativeAcknowledge()) when will it be redelivered?

Tags: apache-pulsar

If we cannot process a message (perhaps due to some timing problem or race condition) and we call

```
consumer.negativeAcknowledge(messageId);
```

When will it be redelivered to retry processing?

I am unable to figure out what the default setting for delivery is from the documentation

- https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-messaging/#negative-acknowledgement
  https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-messaging/#acknowledgement-timeout
  https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/reference-configuration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is 60 seconds.
You can configure it in the consumer:

```java
Consumer<byte[]> consumer = client.newConsumer()
    .topic("my-topic")
    .subscriptionName("my-sub")
    .negativeAckRedelivery(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe()
```